# Normal Distribution with $95\%$ confidence interval

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

```
n <- 10
nsims <- 10000
true_ci_cov <- vector(length=nsims)
est_ci_cov <- vector(length=nsims)
for(i in 1:nsims){
    data<-rnorm(n, mean=1, sd=2)
    mean_dat<-mean(data)
    sd_dat<-sd(data)
    ci_true_low <- mean_dat - 1.96*2/sqrt(n)
    ci_true_high <- mean_dat + 1.96*2/sqrt(n)
    ci_est_low <- mean_dat - 1.96*sd_dat/sqrt(n)
    ci_est_high <- mean_dat + 1.96*sd_dat/sqrt(n)
    true_ci_cov[i] <- (ci_true_high >=1)*(ci_true_low <=1)
    est_ci_cov[i] <- (ci_est_high >=1)*(ci_est_low <=1)
}
mean(true_ci_cov)
mean(est_ci_cov)
```

Here I understood in the code that it is storing the values in an array and returning the mean of that array but I want to understand what is the significance or what does that `mean (true_ci_cov)` and `mean(est_ci_cov)` value represent?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854234/rnorm1-mu-sigma-in-r-to-matlab/53854322) explains what rnorm is doing. Can you decypher that code now line by line?

Comment: I know that bit i can't wrap my head around why we are multiplying both ends of confidence intervals?

Answer (score 1):

In each loop over $i$ this code draws $n$ independent normally distributed rvs $X_1,...,X_n$ with mean $1$ and standard deviation $2\,.$ Then it calculates
$$
\text{mean_dat} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\,,\quad\text{sd_dat}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\text{mean_dat})^2}\,.
$$
Due to random noise, mean_dat will fluctuate around its theoretical value $1\,.$ To know by how much, observe first that the variance of each $X_i$ is $4$ so that
$$
\mathbb E[X_i^2]=5\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathbb E\Big[\text{mean_dat}\Big]=1\,,
$$
and
$$
\mathbb E\Big[\,\text{mean_dat}^2\,\Big]=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\underbrace{\mathbb E[X_i^2]}_{5}+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\not=j}\underbrace{\mathbb E[X_i]\mathbb E[X_j]}_{1}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n5+\frac{n^2-n}{n^2}=\frac{4}{n}+1\,.
$$
Therefore, in theory, the fluctuations of mean_dat have a standard deviation of
\begin{align}\tag{1}
&\sqrt{\mathbb E\Big[\text{mean_dat}^2\Big]-\mathbb E\Big[\text{mean_dat}\Big]^2}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\,.
\end{align}
Likewise, sd_dat fluctuates around its theoretical value $2\,.$ Alternatively to the theoretical standard deviation (1) the code also calculates the standard deviation using the estimated sd_dat instead of 2:
$$\tag{2}
\frac{\text{sd_dat}}{\sqrt{n}}\,.
$$
The code now checks if the drawn mean_dat is within a confidence interval around its theoretical value $1$ where the interval is
$$
\left[1-1.96\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}},1+1.96\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right]\text{ resp. }
\left[1-1.96\frac{\text{sd_dat}}{\sqrt{n}},1+1.96\frac{\text{sd_dat}}{\sqrt{n}}\right]\,.
$$
Because mean_dat is normally distributed, the first interval corresponds to 95% probability. In theory, the last two lines `mean(true_ci_cov)` `mean(est_ci_cov)`
should produce something close to 0.95.

Comment: thanks. What if we make the value of n as 100 from 10. How will that mean(true_ci_ov) and mean(est_ci_cov) change?

Comment: It should converge to its theoretical value 0.95 with a rate of $1/\sqrt{n}$ describing the error. This little piece of code is nothing else than a simple experiment that verifies if -as we know- a Monte carlo simulation has that rate of convergence. You could also view it as a test how independent and normal your random numbers are.